# Python launch external process in its own window on any platform?

Tags: python, console, subprocess, cross-platform

I'm hoping this isn't a dupe. I've searched and searched and tried suggestions from many posts here, but so far I can't find what I'm looking for.

I have a Python 2.7 app which communicates via a second app via sockets. I would like to make it so that when the first Python app is launched, it automatically starts the second one.

The challenge is I'd really like the second app to pop up in its own console window with its own console logging. The catch is my app is used by people on different platforms, so I'd like something that's platform-independent, and so far all I have found that do this use platform-specific things. So I wonder, is this something that's even possible?

The closest thing I've found is to use subprocess.Popen, like this:

```
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'myscript.py'],
        stdout=None,
        stderr=None,
        stdin=None)
```

(I know that I could use sys.executable instead of 'python', but in some cases the second app that needs to run won't be a Python app.)

Anyway the above works except that the output of the second app shows up co-mingled in the same window as the first app. I tried to shell=True to the args for Popen (and then I switched the args to a string as recommended in the Popen documentation), like this:

```
    subprocess.Popen(['python myscript.py'],
        stdout=None,
        stderr=None,
        stdin=None,
        shell=True
        )
```

The result of that (at least on my Mac) is the same as before. The second Python app starts, but its output is co-mingled into the existing console window instead of launching a new one. (And on Windows I can't get that to work at all. I just get an error that "python myscript.py" is not a valid command. Same result if I change the string to "python.exe myscript.py")

I don't need any communication between the apps since I already have everything I need via the sockets. (My app is a game controller engine that connects to an external media controller which could be Unity, Unreal, Python, etc.)

I tried various incarnations of the "old" ways, including os.spawn, os.system and a bunch of other things, but none of them give the behavior I'm hoping for. I also tried to use the subprocess convenience functions, but as far as I can tell those all block until the subprocess terminates.

Frankly at this point the best I can think of is just using a batch file (though that would have to be OS-specific as far as I know)?

So I wonder if anyone knows whether want I want to do is possible?

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: The output is comingled because you have to redirect the standard output, etc. which you have set to `None`.

Comment: You could use a GUI such as `tkinter` to pop up that other window.